# How to hide text under the minimap when using Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

When using Atom a line of code is too long, it goes under the minimap, and I can't scroll to it or see it except through the minimap.

How can I make it so the minimap is "off" of the editor, so that it's not on top of the code?

Answer (score 0):

When minimap's `absoluteMode` is false, it is taken out of the editor window, so that your can scroll right on the main editor window and not accidentally click on minimap while working.

Here's how to change it:

1. File > Config...
2. Search for minimap
3. Change `absoluteMode` to false

It should look like this when you're done

```
minmap:
  absoluteMode: false
```